# using System; in C# vs using namespace std; in C++

Tags: c#, c++

Why is it that `using namespace std;` is considered poor practice in C++, but `using System;` is considered good practice in C#? They seem to be analogous (bringing standard library stuff into the global namespace).

Comment: Who says it's good practice in c#?

Comment: I would argue that `using namespace std;` is fine in implementation files; just keep it out of header files.  However, there are nicer and more explicit alternatives like `using std::cout;` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: MonoDevelop automatically includes it as the first line of any C# file

Comment: @Aggieboy And I would argue it is not "fine" in implementation files either (unless in a limited scope.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Isn't a cpp file a form of limited scope? A `using namespace` *in a source file* is equivalent to a `using` directive in C# scope-wise.  If someone shows that even this scope is too permissive, then perhaps.

Comment: @Aggieboy I mean scope more limited than a `.cpp` file. A function, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C# has no free-standing functions.

The problem with `using namespace std` in C++ is when the compiler suddenly decides to call the `std::` function instead of your function which is not surprising with names like `count`, `distance` or `find` being template functions that take just about anything.

This is much less of a problem in C# because C# does not have free-standing functions and it has stricter implicit conversions (e.g. you can't pass an `int` to a function that expects a pointer).

Answer (score 19):

In C#, a `using` directive only impacts the file or namespace scope where it is placed.

If you include `using namespace std;` in a c++ header file, it impacts not only that file, but every file that includes it.  This creates conflict potential in *other people's files*.

You could easily argue that it's not "best practice" in C#, but the risk involved is dramatically lower than in C++ as it only impacts the file or namespace scope where the directive is placed.

Comment: Wherever does the OP speak of puttig it into his headers? Should add some arguments for implementation files...